Authorization not working even after successfully logging in to ASP .NET Core MVC app
Implemented JWT authentication in my application, with this code in the Program.cs:
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(AuthConstants.AUTH_TOKEN)
    .AddCookie(AuthConstants.AUTH_TOKEN, options =>
    {
        options.Cookie.Name = AuthConstants.AUTH_TOKEN;
        options.LoginPath = "/Home/Login";
    })
    .AddJwtBearer(options =>
    {
        options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            ValidateIssuer = true,
            ValidateAudience = true,
            ValidateLifetime = true,
            ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
            ValidIssuer = builder.Configuration["Jwt:Issuer"],
            ValidAudience = builder.Configuration["Jwt:Audience"],
            IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(builder.Configuration["Jwt:Key"]))
        };
    });

Also, I included authentication and authorization middleware there:
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

Here is my UserController which are all of the authorized route
[Authorize]
public class UserController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult Dashboard(string token)
    {
        return View();
    }
}

This is the Login method in HomeController:
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginDTO loginUser)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var token = _loginService.GenerateToken(loginUser, _configuration);

        if (token != null)
        {
            var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
            var jwtToken = tokenHandler.ReadJwtToken(token);

            CookieOptions cookieOptions = new CookieOptions
            {
                HttpOnly = true,
                Secure = true,
                Expires = jwtToken.ValidTo
            };
            
            Response.Cookies.Append(AuthConstants.AUTH_TOKEN, token, cookieOptions);
            TempData["Success"] = "Login Successful";

            string returnUrl = HttpContext.Request.Query["returnUrl"];

            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(returnUrl) && Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl))
                return Redirect(returnUrl);

            return RedirectToAction("Dashboard", "User");
        }

        TempData["Error"] = "Invalid credentials, please try again.";
    }

    return View(loginUser);
}

After that, this will return me to login page with return url, which means that authorize not working here.

According to your codes, I guess the reason why it always redirect to the default authorize scheme. The default authorize scheme is the cookie not the JWT which makes it redirect to the login page.
I suggest you could try to modify it to the JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme and test again. [Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
